# My PC with iTunes is dead; how do I save my CD sourced MUSIC still on iPhone to iTunes in cloud?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, backup, music

My iPhone backup PC that had my iTunes backup is dead. I'd loaded a lot of my CD's to the iTunes in that PC. How do I back up my iphone MUSIC contents to a cloud back up, including the CDs which are still on my phone (and had been backed up to now dead PC)?

I already managed to do a similar thing with the photos that were really on the PC in sync folder, by saving photos that would have been lost by copying them to my phone before converting to icloud backup.

Comment: You might be able to reverse sync on a new computer.  You need to list versions of what you are using.  Also Apple is definitely more secure then the early iPhone and iPod days. Unless this is built into the OS/iTunes my guess is there is no way today.